# How can I get values from genereated QSpinBoxes?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I set the number of spinboxes in the previous window and then, according to the code below, they are added in the next window, but when I click the button, I need to pick up the value from each generated spinbox, but at the moment the value is transmitted only from the last one.
How do I get the value from each spinbox?

Thank you!

```
class CreateSpuWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, value):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi('ui/statement_spu_1.ui', self)
    self.value = value  # Quantity pf spinBoxes 
    for i in range(value):
        self.spu_label = QLabel(self)
        self.spu_label.setText(f"SPU №{i+1}. PP:")
        self.quantity_pp = QSpinBox(self)
        self.quantity_pp.setValue(1)
        self.quantity_pp.setMinimum(1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.spu_label, 2 * i, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.quantity_pp, 2 * i, 1)
    self.next_tu_spu_2Button.clicked.connect(self.next_wind_spu_btn)
    self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.back_btn_cl)

def next_wind_spu_btn(self):
    data = []
    # Get a value from spinbox
    for i in str(self.quantity_pp.value()):
        data.append(i)
    print(data)
    quantity_spu = self.value
    self.ReadyTableSpuWindow = ReadyTableSpuWindow(quantity_spu)
    self.ReadyTableSpuWindow.show()
    self.close()

def back_btn_cl(self):
    self.close()
    self.QuantitySpuWindow = QuantitySpuWindow()
    self.QuantitySpuWindow.show()
```

Comment: Create a list as attribute of the instance (`self.spinboxes = []`) before the loop and append the spinboxes when you create them.

Comment: Ok, I have got this in list: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox object at 0x05CCB580, but how can I get a value from the name of object?

Comment: If you are trying to get value using it's objectName, that's a little tricky and you probably have to use findChildren on a parent. To get the value, you typically call value() as a function. In your case: `mylist[2]. value()` for example.

Comment: @IvanW that's not a "name", it's the printable representation of the object. The list already contains references to those widgets: `for spin in self.spinboxes:` `print(spin.value())`.